# RDM more v2022.3.19.0 not rdp connection remote windows via balabit firewall

Tags: windows, firewall, remote-desktop

I use remote-desktop-manager v2022.3.19.0
for connect to some Unix remote hosts and Windows remote hosts.
Connection for some hosts via host jump (balabit security)
After upgrade version over v2022.3.19.0 try connect to Windows remote host via balabit firewall ended some blink screen.

RDP connect to windows remote host without balabit firewall - worked good.

Settings RDP session:

[image][image]
[image]
[image][image][image][image]

Had to downgrade to v2022.3.19.0.
Versions more v2022.3.19.0 not working.

How solve this problem?